# Setting IO Priority of low instead of Very Low

Tags: winapi

I am trying to set the IO Priority of a process to LOW. Currently I am calling the SetProiorityClass Function with PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN. This sets the IO Priority to "VeryLow". How do I got about setting it one level higher to "LOW"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686219(VS.85).aspx

Comment: When I pass in BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, Process Priority class becomes BELOW NORMAL but the IO Priority still is normal

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/226419